# html extracting contents of a div class java

Tags: java, html

Ive searched everywhere and cant find a good answer. I'm trying to extract the contents of 
    `<div class="directions">` and print it out. is there a simple way to print out the contents of the class, not using jsoup?

```
<div class="directions">

    <h3>Directions</h3>
    <div class="directLeft" itemprop="recipeInstructions">
        <div id="msgDirections" style="display:none"></div>

        <ol>

            <li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">Preheat oven to 275 degrees F (135 degrees C).</span></li>

            <li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">Combine the margarine, salt, garlic salt, Worcestershire sauce and pumpkin seeds. Mix thoroughly and place in shallow baking dish.</span></li>

            <li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">Bake for 1 hour, stirring occasionally.</span></li>

        </ol>

        <a href="/recipe/spiced-pumpkin-seeds/kitchenview.aspx" id="lnkKitchenView" class="linkPrefersSupportingMembership rp-btn crnrs3px grayBrdr clr-gray gray fl-left">Kitchen-Friendly View</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: "*is there a simple way to print out the contents of the class, not using jsoup*" what is wrong with jsoup? It seems like this is perfect library for this job.

Comment: Use [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/) if your content is reasonably small. JSoup would be much simpler though.

Comment: @Mena its quite big, ive used indexOf() but cant seem to think of an efficient way to use it.

Comment: @user3250337 then I suggest you use [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) or even [StaX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html). Lots of low-level fun in perspective. And yes, `String.indexOf` is definitely **not** where you want to go for parsing markup.

Comment: What is "quite big" in actual file size? Are you getting OOMs when trying to parse? jsoup's dom is more compact than w3c (less fields).

Comment: How about [frizzle](https://github.com/on-site/frizzle)?